# Call to SOAP service doesn't work for everyone, but only in IE

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I've got a SOAP service that I am calling to auto dial other people when you click a button on a webpage. All I pass in is the number I want to dial and the number of the user and the phone will call out.

I can get this to work fine, and everytime I press the button the phone dials. However for certain users they can press the button and have it dial out, but any time after that it does not work. They can press the button as many times they want, but after the first time nothing will happen. The code still fires, and I can step through it to see that.

We tried this initially in IE, but when we moved to Chrome to try it out the call button worked every time without fail. So my assumption is that there may be some setting in IE that is different between myself and them that is stopping it from working. A quick check through though didn't turn anything up.

Does anyone know of any potential settings or anything else that might be causing this problem?

I haven't included any code initially as I wasn't sure how useful it might be, but if it helps then I can post up the SOAP request and the C# code to call it.

**EDIT**

The code is pasted below, first off is the SOAP call itself with some example numbers in. I can run this from the web service itself using SoapUI and it works every time. The code is the method that calls the soap, first looking for the current user's number and then using that and the destination number that is passed in. These are then passed through to the call.

This is all I have access to, as the webservice methods etc have been developed by a third party and we have no access to it.

**Example SOAP:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:Dial>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:line>1111</tem:line>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:destination>2222</tem:destination>
      </tem:Dial>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Code:**

```
public void Call(string destination, string username)
{
    var line = GetNumber(username);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    {
        var paWebServiceClient = new PAWebServiceClient("PAHttpEndPoint");

        paWebServiceClient.Dial(line, destination); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, post relevant code. Nobody can guess why every 2nd Tuesday the button doesn't work for 2 people.

Comment: @Equalsk Done, added to OP

Comment: What does `GetNumber` do? Contact a database? Can you post the code for that?